# Effect like Interface Builder connection lines on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, drawing

Hi I'd like little bit of help on something. In my app, I have a UITableView which is populated with custom cells that represent images. (i.e. selecting a row displays a picture in an image view).

What I would like to do, is have an icon in the custom cell that I could drag to one of a series of image views. Similar to the way you can drag a line in IB to set connections. Once the user releases their finger I will have it check what part of the screen they released it and if it is one one of these rects that represent the picture frames, it will populate the picture frame with the image and the line will disappear.

I have never drawn lines in my app before so thats not something I know how to do (so im just looking for a link to a tutorial or class definition) and second, what problems will I have since the start point of the line is in a UITableViewCell and the end point is in the main view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually done this before, so I can give you the exact code :D

This is only the drawing part, you implement the touch events (in a separate class, otherwise remove the self.userInteractionEnabled = NO; in .m file

The BOOL dragged tells the LineView if the line should be drawn.

**LineView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LineView : UIView 
{
    CGPoint start;
    CGPoint end;

    BOOL dragged;
}

@property CGPoint start, end;
@property BOOL dragged;

@end
```

**LineView.m**

```
#import "LineView.h"

@implementation LineView

@synthesize start, end, dragged;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame: frame])
    {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark Setters
-(void) setStart: (CGPoint) s
{
    start = s;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void) setEnd: (CGPoint) e
{
    end = e;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

#define LINE_COLOR   [UIColor redColor]
#define CIRCLE_COLOR [UIColor redColor]

#define LINE_WIDTH    5
#define CIRCLE_RADIUS 10

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if(dragged) {
        [LINE_COLOR setStroke];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, start.x, start.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, end.x, end.y);        
        CGContextSetLineWidth(c, LINE_WIDTH); 
        CGContextClosePath(c);
        CGContextStrokePath(c);

        [CIRCLE_COLOR setFill];
        CGContextAddArc(c, start.x, start.y, CIRCLE_RADIUS, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
        CGContextClosePath(c);
        CGContextFillPath(c);

        CGContextAddArc(c, end.x, end.y, CIRCLE_RADIUS, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
        CGContextClosePath(c);
        CGContextFillPath(c);
    }
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: And I hope that you know that this view has to be above all other views.

To detect where the line was dragged to, use the touchesEnded: in the class that handles touch events

Comment: okay i've started to work at it and realized I know much less than I need to. Am I implementing this when the user drags their finger out of the button in the tableViewCell?

Comment: Here's my suggestion (I don't know much about your project, but I hope this helps): implement the touch events in a main view (you mentioned it in your question). Than check if the line was ended in the area of that picture (CGRectContainsPoint). Also, if the user doesn not touch the table view cell, just set the dragged to no, and the line won't be drawn.